# Typescript fields with special characters

Tags: json, node.js, typescript

We need to call a REST API from out node.js code in Typescript and would like to have corresponding types for requests and responses. 
Unfortunately, JSON for the interface we are given contains fields such as:

```
{...
    "@ID": "1234567890",
        ...
    "@Name": "something",
    "#text": "content",
...
}
```

We have been told, that this stems from a limitation of the other end's automated "JSONifier" and cannot be changed. How do we set up interfaces that fit for this?
The following obviously won't work:

```
  export interface Request {
    @ID: string;
    @Name: string;
    #text: string;
    ...
  }
```

Comment: I rememberd that it is indeed possible to declare the fields as '@ID' and access via req['@ID']. I think that is a very ugly solution though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just like JS objects, you can surround the names with quotes, like so:

```
  export interface Request {
    "@ID": string;
    "@Name": string;
    "#text": string;
  }
```

Comment: Is there a way to use such an attribute in the constructor of the implementation class, something like this: `public "@Name": string, ...`
If I try that, the compiler doesn't like it

Comment: Classes require a bit specialized syntax, you can use computed property names: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ0PQA4FcBGIAlsNANoBEAAgHJgC2ApuQLoBc0EALgE6EB2AcwDcqAL6pUweHy7QAZomgBeaHwYB3OIhEL4FGvSbNl0AOQAJBiBDwAhKaFA