# Declaring a field with a colon in an interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm receiving a JSON object similar to below.

```
{
    "sub": "5354f0a7-b904-4831",
    "email_verified": true,
    "custom:group": "buyer",
    "aud": "30lhep4eammk443j1",
    "event_id": "93bf3295-2aa2-4dad-a0a4",
    "token_use": "id"
}
```

and to map the values of above, I have created an interface like this,

```
export interface Token {
    email?: string
    sub?: string
    aud?: string
    email_verified?: boolean
    token_use?: string
}
```

when I try to access the value of *custom:group*, TypeScript is showing an error since the field is not defined in the interface.

```
const group = obj[custom:group];
```

to overcome this issue, is it possible to declare *custom:group* field in the interface since it is having a colon?

Comment: Just surround the key declaration with quotes, eg `'custom:group': string` (and access with a string inside bracket notation)

Comment: [Typescript fields with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541406)

Comment: @CertainPerformance, yes, it's working. Thanks