# how to call an element which has '@' on it in typescript?

Tags: reactjs, string, typescript, api, types

I have this API data, which is like this

```
data = [{
 @type: "mobile",
 number: '02302030203'
  ...
 },
 ...
]
```

Then right now, I'm using react with typescript so i need to declare the element first for me to be able to access it.

So my question is, how should I declare the `@type` in typescript like this:

```
export interface DataTypes {
  number: number;
  @type: string; <---- how?
}
```

and how will i call it like this:

`data[i].number`

`data[i].@type` <---- how?

Answer (score 0):

```
export interface DataTypes {
  number: number;
  "@type": string; <---- answer
}

data[i].['@type']
```

Got the answer in here.. Thanks anyways
[Typescript fields with special characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541406/typescript-fields-with-special-characters)